# LibCurl FTP directory list of a subdirectory

Tags: c++, ftp, libcurl

I'm new to this libcurl stuff and struggling trying to get directory content of a sub-folder from the site I connect to.

I can successfully provide user and password to an .

Once connected, I want to get a list of files in a folder "subfolder1".  No matter what I'm trying, I am only getting the directory content of the root as connected.

I'm seriously spinning wheels here and need some help.  I'm not even going to post the many iterative attempts as it might confuse the final answer that I might find here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

UPDATE...

Although it doesn't make sense that I can't issue my own FTP commands to force changing to a directory, THEN get the directory list, by adding

```
curl_easy_setopt(myCurl, CURLOPT_URL, FullURLToSubFolder );
```

appears to force it and I get proper directory listing.